# How to get the nominator/denominator of a Fraction object

Tags: python, fractions

I have four variables that are added as fractions:

```
n1 = input("Denominator 1")
d1 = input("Denominator 1")
n2 = input("Denominator 1")
d2 = input("Denominator 1")

def fraction(n1,d1,n2,d2):
    a = Fraction(n1,d1)
    b = Fraction(n2,d2)
    print(a+b)
    return

fraction(n1,d1,n2,d2)
```

The answer comes out as something like `23/45`.

How would I separate the two numbers and remove the divisor?

```
23
---
45
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = Fraction(n1, d1)
b = Fraction(n2, d2)
c = a+b
print(c.numerator, c.denominator, sep="\n---\n")
```

The next time that you'll need something like this, do `dir(c)`

you'll get back something like:

```
 [..., '_sub', 'conjugate', 'denominator', 'from_decimal', 'from_float', 'imag', 'limit_denominator', 'numerator', 'real']
```

(also, `help(c)` or looking at the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/fractions.html) is useful)

Answer (score 2):

Use `Fraction.numerator` and `Fraction.denominator`:

```
>>> from fractions import Fraction
>>> a = Fraction(1, 2)
>>> b = Fraction(2, 3)
>>> tot = a+b
>>> print(tot, tot.numerator, tot.denominator)
7/6 7 6
```